# Instagram Api comment post

Tags: api, permissions, instagram

I am building an instagram application. However, when I try to post comment I get this Error message

Error:400
Error:ApiError
This client ID is not permitted to POST comments

I am able to like and unlike though

Has anyone experience this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a restricted endpoint. You have apply and be approved (whitelisted) by Instagram.

See: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/